# Hydrogen in a box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, hydrogen

I would like to approximate the 1S wave function of a system constrained to a box $\{(x,y,z)|x\in[0,a],y\in[0,b],z\in[0,c]\}$, subject to the potential of the hydrogen atom. I have proposed the variational ansatz

$$ \psi=N e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}/\lambda}\cos({\pi x/a} )\cos(\pi y/b)\cos(\pi z/c)  $$

and tried to integrate Hamiltonian of this wave function to find the minimising parameter $ \lambda $. The problem is that I could not solve it in Mathematica. Is my wavefunction proposed in a wrong way? Or does Mathematica have a problem?

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is solvable in that geometry?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I believe OP does not really mean "to solve" but "to approximate", as they appear to be using the variational method.

Comment: Yes I want to approximate indeed.Think this problem like particle in a box ,0 and a are boundaries.

Comment: What does this have to do with hydrogen?

Comment: I will find the wawe function and plot with varying a,b and c.Note that this is particle in a box problem using 1s hydrogen atom.

Comment: If you're looking for the wave functions of a particle in a 3D box with zero (or fixed) potential, look no further: https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Quantum_Mechanics/05.5%3A_Particle_in_Boxes/Particle_in_a_3-dimensional_box . There really isn't much to it with the method of separation of variables.

Comment: Okey but I need for hydrogen

Comment: @umos: what do you mean by that? Those solutions are for *any particle*, just choose the right mass and the box dimensions $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: I would like to confine indeed the hydrogen in a box,and make interpretations from a trial wave function as I posted above.

Comment: @umos: Ok, much clearer now. Basically you have a 3D box with an electron in it, and a proton at the centre?

Comment: I have the hydrogen in 1s state.That is only.İgnore electron,vs.I have the hydrogen in 1s in a 3D potential well(box).

Comment: The problem is not well posed unless you specify boundary conditions, e.g. with $n\cdot \nabla \psi=0$. it depicts something like a "hydrogen crystal".

Comment: So you have an atom of hydrogen in the box?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I could not solve it in Mathematica"? What specifically were you not able to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Since Cartesian solutions do not have good angular momentum by themselves, you would have better luck by trying a spherical flat well, for which the solutions are in terms of spherical Bessel and Hanckel functions (the latter are needed if you don't want to impose a hard wall condition at some radius $r_0$.)   At least you could make sense of an $s$-state, with $\ell=0$, since $s$-states are supposed to be spherically symmetric (i.e. depend only on $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$).  This would also simply the Schrodinger equation as there would be no centripetal term, and the spherical functions would collapse to regular trig and exponential functions.

In spherical coordinates, I suppose the analog of your guess function would be something like
$$
\psi(r)=A e^{-r/\lambda}\cos(k_r r)\, ,
$$
if you insist on a hard wall at some distance $r_0$, and you could solve the 1d Schrodinger equation for the radial coordinate using the usual trick of solving for $R(r)=r\psi(r)$.  This way the boundary condition is on $R$ and
$$
\lim_{r\to 0} R(r)=0
$$
so the boundary condition on the 1d probability density $R^2(r)$ is 
as it should be.

The general difficulty is that good guesses for wavefunctions are dictated by the physics of the problem, which in your case would be the potential.  The solution in terms of trig functions are good when a large part of the potential is flat, which would not be the case for anything close to a hydrogen-type potential.   On the other hand, the exponential dependence $e^{-\lambda r}$ arises because the potential is dominated by the Coulomb term at $r\to\infty$, something that can't be realistically modelled with a flat potential constrained to a box.

Comment: Explain what you mean by a *"spherical flat well"*, please?

Comment: Thank you and could you write any function for my situation if you can?

Comment: @Gert: constant potential in $r$, like $V(r)=V_0$ for $0\le r\le r_0$.

Comment: @umos added a small bit to answer your query.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: that would be quite easy but so far removed from the actual potential in an H-atom.

Comment: @Gert Amen to that.  The basic idea of somehow approximating the solution by looking at a box is *extremely* suspicious but... that's what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero:For instance I have used  a wave function  in the post$e^{-r/\lambda} sin()....$. Could you propose me a trial wave function?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero:What is $k_r$ exactly,could you expand?And  what type of function I use if I wolud like to solve in cylindrical coordinates?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, your wave function is proposed in the wrong way:

1) It should be separable.

$e^{r^2}$ is separable, $e^{||r||}$ is not; nevertheless, why not $e^0$?

2) It should vanish at the box walls.

$\cos{x}$ doesn't not vanish at $x=0$, but $\sin{x}$ does.

Comment: Okey change the boundaries from [0,a] to [-a/2,a/2].But why exponential part is wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.